# Request data with NTLM authentication by using ajax on blackberry

Tags: ajax, authentication, web, ntlm

I want to connect to the server which supports NTLM authentication, and I'm using the following code snippet to request data:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: jsonpCallback,
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('AD-ENT\\' + u + ":" + p));
    },
    success: successCallback,
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 401) {
            alert("Authentication Failed");
        }
    },
    complete: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            ....
    }
});
```

But when invoking this code, following authentication dialog popup:

[pic]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMwce.jpg

It seems like it is not effective to request data with authentication.

So did anyone know this issue and can help me?
 - How to supress the browser's authentication dialog?
 - How to request data with NTLM authentication by using ajax request?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you forget to attach the picture (there is only `[pic]` placeholder)?

Comment: Sorry, I've put an image url above.